Computing SHA256 in a SAFE CLR assembly
We have build a .NET function that (among other things) need to compute a SHA256 hash. For this, we have called the System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 class from .NET Framework. After adding the CLR assembly in SQL Server with WITH PERMISSION_SET=SAFE, we were able to call this function from SQL Server (including creating some persisted columns based on this function). This all worked fine when we had installed the .NET Framework updates from 2024-04.
After installing the .NET Framework updates from 2024-05, this is no longer working. When we call this function, we are getting an error which says: "Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host. [...] The demanded resources were: MayLeakOnAbort [...]"
Apparently, Microsoft has recently added the MayLeakOnAbort attribute to the SHA256 class (see current version vs older version). If we recreate the CLR assembly with WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE, it works. However, as mentioned in Security in the CLR World Inside SQL Server:

"MayLeakOnAbort means that the object might cause a resource leak on termination if it is not protected by a safe handle or some other means of ensuring the release of resources. [...] Any of these conditions can undermine the security of the server. SQL Server [...] manages memory resources, so memory requests are allocated from SQL Server’s available memory, not from the Windows pool. Keeping tight control over such resources is critical to maintaining reliability and stability of SQL Server. Just be aware that SQL Server ignores these restrictions for UNSAFE assemblies. That’s yet another reason why you don’t want to install UNSAFE assemblies, or at least why you should do a thorough code review before installing any."

My question is: How can we compute a SHA256 hash in a way that can be called from SQL Server in a SAFE CLR assembly? Is there any freely available library or piece of code for this purpose (besides the code in .NET Framework, which is no longer safe, in the latest updates)?

Why are you trying to import CLR assemblies to compute SHA256 hashes when SQL Server already supports this functionality with HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', ...)?

@AlwaysLearning i'm guessing he does something else in code that needs hash among other things

Then, perhaps, they should return the unhashed value from the CLR, and then  use HASBYTES to hash it in T-SQL, @siggemannen . If their goal is to just hash the value using SHA256, then using CLR makes little sense.

Yeah, i try not to expand the problem scope too much, but maybe you're right and it's possible to skip the whole CLR thing altogether. @OP is screwed anyway, i don't think one can use such class with the attribute without changing the SAFEty mode. Well, one can perhaps re-implement the class yourself

You can add the DLL with a login that is created from a signature of that DLL, then allow that login to access UNSAFE. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/232427/220697 and https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/

@AlwaysLearning, after hashing the CLR function makes some string manipulation that should be faster in .NET than in T-SQL.

@Charlieface, my concern is more about stability than about security in this case, because MayLeakOnAbort suggests a memory leak is possible, so there are some scenarios where we may end-up with a lot of unusable memory allocated to CLR. So this is why I am looking for another piece of code that can compute a SHA256 hash in .NET, without risking memory leaks.

@AlwaysLearning, it may be a good idea to compute the hash in T-SQL and then pass it to the CLR function to do the string manipulation. Thanks for reminding me about HASHBYTES, we will try to explore this scenario, but the original question remains.

In the end, we implemented a new CLR function that uses the hash computed in SQL, as suggested by @AlwaysLearning.
